# rails pg db migration undefined method `database_authenticatable' for Devise Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

`undefined method database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0xd715388>`

The migration is:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of devise are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, devise changed it's generated migration style from

```
create_table(:user) do |t|
  t.database_authenticatable
end
```

to

```
create_table(:user) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
end
```

after version 2.0.

UPDATE: See this [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style).

Comment: +1  Useful.  But what if this is an existing rails application and the user migration is one of the early ones, what is the correct approach?  Should I edit that? Delete it and redo a brand new one?  Do a migration to drop the old, add the new?  The correct answer to these questions will help guide me to a good solution

Comment: I check the above wiki reference - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style - and it is helpful, e.g. "You will need to change your original Devise migration(s) to not use the Before helpers, but instead use the fields listed..."

Comment: maybe put the update link to wiki at the top of this post instead of the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  # t.encryptable
  # t.confirmable
  # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
  # t.token_authenticatable


  t.timestamps
end
```