# error trying to migrate test environment database in rails, possibly devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to run a migration on my test db and i get this error. I can create it and drop it but not migrate it.

```
undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fccae8e1bb0>/Users/McGroarty/projects/gll/db/migrate/20111105225808_devise_create_users.rb:4:in `block in up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:434:in `create_table'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/Users/McGroarty/projects/gll/db/migrate/20111105225808_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
NoMethodError: undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fccae8e1bb0>
/Users/McGroarty/projects/gll/db/migrate/20111105225808_devise_create_users.rb:4:in `block in up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:434:in `create_table'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/Users/McGroarty/projects/gll/db/migrate/20111105225808_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/Users/McGroarty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem "airbrake"
gem 'ancestry' #rails g migration add_ancestry_to_things ancestry:string
gem "annotate", "~> 2.6.1", group: [:development]
gem "arel"
gem 'autotest-rails', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'binding_of_caller', group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>2.0.1'
gem "breadcrumbs"
gem 'cache_digests'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'
gem "capybara", :git=>"https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git", group: [:development,:test]
gem 'carrierwave' #rails g uploader YOURMODEL
gem 'chronic'
gem 'cityhash'
gem 'colorize', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'coveralls', require: false, group: [:development,:test]
gem 'cucumber', "<= 1.3.1", group: [:development,:test]
gem "cucumber-rails", require: false, group: [:development,:test]
gem "coffee-rails","~>3.2.1"
gem 'coffee-script'
gem "compass", "~> 0.12.3"
gem "compass-rails"
gem "csv_builder"
gem 'dalli'
gem 'database_cleaner', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'decent_exposure'
gem 'devise' #rails g devise:install && rails g devise MODEL
gem 'execjs'
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.0.0"
gem "factory_girl_generator", ">= 0.0.1"
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'ffi', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'faker'
gem 'fog'
gem "friendly_id", '~> 4.0'
gem 'geokit',"1.6.7"
gem 'gmaps4rails', "1.4.5"
gem 'guard-jasmine', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'guard-spork', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'identity_cache'
gem 'jasmine', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'jasminerice', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'jquery-rails','2.1.4'
gem 'json'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'launchy', ">= 2.3.0", group: [:development,:test]
gem 'lazybox'
gem 'libnotify', '~>0.5.2', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'meta_request', group: :development
gem "meta_search"
gem 'mimetype-fu'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'nested_form', :git => "https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git"
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 2' #bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install
gem 'parallel_tests', group: [:development,:test]
gem "prawn"
gem 'pry', group: :development
gem 'pry-rails', group: :development
gem "rabl"
gem "rack-test", group: [:development,:test]
gem 'rack-rewrite'
gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
#gem 'rails_view_annotator', group: :development
gem "rake",">=10.1.1"
gem 'rb-fsevent', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'remotipart' # Ajax image uploading
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'rspec', '>= 2.8.0', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.8.0', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'rvm-capistrano', group: [:development,:test]
gem "sass", "~> 3.2.14"
gem 'sass-rails', "~>3.2.0"
gem 'simple_form', '>=2.0'
gem 'simplecov', require: false, group: [:development,:test]
gem 'spork', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem "thinking-sphinx", "3.0.0"
gem 'thor'
gem "tinymce-rails", :git => 'https://github.com/newbray/tinymce-rails.git'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3', :require => 'uglifier'
gem 'unf'
gem 'unicode'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'whenever'
gem "will_paginate"
gem 'workflow'
#gem 'ZenTest', '~>4.9.4', group: [:development,:test]
gem 'zeus-parallel_tests', group: [:development,:test]
```

I've tried backdating version of devise, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186586/rails-pg-db-migration-undefined-method-database-authenticatable-for-devise-use) article but still no joy.

I cloned this repo recently. My development database is working fine.
does anybody have any suggestions as to why this is occurring?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630768/undefined-method-database-authenticatable-for-activerecordconnectionadapte

Comment: @MichaelPapile, i refernced that question  in my Q dude. READ!

Comment: Umm you are the one that needs to read.  The question I refer to is NOT the one you referenced. It also appears to be your problem. Result 2 on Google for database_authenticatable

Comment: Look at your migration file name.  It is from 2011.  You need to update it, it is not compatible with today's devise which is exactly what I linked.

Comment: i am not using "today's" devise. I am running bundle exec bundle to keep versions in date. Any way, I am past that bit now.

Comment: Run `bundle list` in that project root directory to see what version of devise you are running.  You do not have it locked to any version in your Gemfile. I suspect it may be a newer version and you may not know it.  If you cloned your repo and did not check in Gemfile.lock bundle will give you the latest version.